# Ansible debugger - Can you redo previous tasks?

Tags: debugging, ansible

I'm using the Ansible debugger, using commands:
p(print variables)
r(edo)
c(ontinue)
q(uit)

Once the playbook gets to the step it fails on, I often wish I could go back and re-do previous tasks, before the task that failed.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In respect to your question

> ... go back and re-do previous tasks ...

this seems to be not possible according the documentation [playbooks_debugger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#enabling-the-debugger) since

> You have access to all of the features of the debugger in the context of the task

only.